# Are the mass ,diameter and age of the Universe absolute quantities?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, relativity

[Mass of the observable Universe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe) is known to be 1.50×10^53 kg. Age is approximately known to be 13.7 billion years. Universe is a sphere with diameter 8.8X 10^26 m.

Mass,Length intervals and Time intervals are relative quantities.

My question is: Are the mass,diameter and age of the Universe absolute quantities(independent of the frame of reference)?

Comment: I suggest you re-post it on Physics SE in a slightly different way as follows: Are the mass and age of the Universe frame dependent?

Comment: What does "absolute" mean? Mass of the universe is not known and may even be infinite. The mass of the *observable* universe that you cite has no particular objective significance as it depends on our relative location and observation capabilities. The age is somewhat more significant, assuming that the Bing Bang started everything that is rather than was just a local event in a larger braneworld, etc.

Comment: @Conifold Yes. You got it right. I am talking about whatever mass the Universe has must be absolute in the sense that it is same for every possible observer in Universe. The same holds true for Age of the Universe. I edit the question to mention observable universe for mass.

Comment: @MarcoOcram I will give it another try if I don’t get an answer here.

Comment: Apparently cosmologists think the answer is yes to both, at least as a matter of convention. They speak of THE age of the universe and all this missing mass, which must be missing wrt some standard.

Comment: @MarcoOcram Thanks for the suggestion. It worked.

Comment: @Annika Yes. At least Age is absolute. Mass and Diameter is also absolute as a whole(including both observable and unobservable Universe.)